# Will sending -removeAllAnimations to a layer also propagate to all it's sublayers?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I wonder if sublayer animations would continue to play if I send -removeAllAnimations to a parent layer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the documentation for `removeAllAnimations`:

> Remove all animations attached to the ***receiver***.

You'll need to iterate through the sublayers and remove animations from them as well:

```
for (CALayer* layer in [containerLayer sublayers]) {
  [layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```