# Removing all current animations when UIView dealloc still leaving reference

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I have a UIView subclass which is being allocated and dealloc'ed frequently within an iOS project. I added `[self.layer removeAllAnimations];` to try to remove all animations before destroying the object. Occassionally, I still get `-[ClassName animationDidStop:finished:]: message sent to deallocated instance`. Now, shouldn't removing animations kill that delegate and prevent it from trying to call animationDidStop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at ["Will sending -removeAllAnimations to a layer also propagate to all it's sublayers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180336/will-sending-removeallanimations-to-a-layer-also-propagate-to-all-its-sublayers) which may be a possible answer to your question.

Comment: I tried doing this and setting the delegate of each layer to nil but I still receive the same error. I also tried looping and removing subviews with no success.

Comment: Does this also happen on a device?

Comment: I have been testing on a device. An iPad (1st generation) to be exact.

Comment: for (CALayer *layer in [[imageLayer.sublayers copy] autorelease]) {
  [layer removeAllAnimations];
  [layer removeFromSuperlayer]; 
  layer = nil;
 }